# raise_error spec not returning true in Rspec 3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following class, that I am trying to write a spec for:

```
module IntegrationError
  class Error < StandardError; end
  class BadRequest < IntegrationError::Error; end
  class LogicProblem < IntegrationError::Error; end

  def raise_logic_error!(message)
    raise IntegrationError::LogicProblem, message
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.error e.message
    e.backtrace.each do |line|
      Rails.logger.error line if line.include?('integrations')
    end
  end

  def raise_bad_request!(message)
    raise IntegrationError::BadRequest, message
  end

  def log_bad_request!(message)
    Rails.logger.info message
  end
end
```

with spec

```
RSpec.describe 'IntegrationError', type: :integration do
  let!(:klass) { Class.new { include IntegrationError } }

  describe '#log_bad_request!' do
    it 'logs it' do
      expect(klass.new.log_bad_request!('TESTME')).to be_truthy
    end
  end

  describe '#raise_bad_request!' do
    it 'raises it' do
      binding.pry
      expect(klass.new.raise_bad_request!('TESTME')).to raise_error 
    end
  end
end
```

the raise_bad_request test returns the error instead of true.  Anyone have thoughts on how to write this better to it passes?

I'm using Rails 4 and Rspec 3.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `raise_error` matcher you need to pass a block to expect instead of a value:

`expect { klass.raise_bad_request!('TESTME') }.to raise_error`

That should do it!

Answer (score 4):

If I recall correctly, I believe you need to pass the expectation a block when your raising, like this:

```
describe '#raise_bad_request!' do
  it 'raises it' do
    binding.pry
    expect{klass.new.raise_bad_request!('TESTME')}.to raise_error 
  end
end
```

See [docs here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-11/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher)